# How to reference the instance of the outside class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm inside an anonymous inner class and wanting to reference the instance of the outside class. In Java it can be referenced using `.this` preceded by the class name to resolve ambiguity. Like: `MainActivity.this`. How can I achieve the same in Kotlin? Because the compiler is complaining `'expression 'this' cannot be a selector(occur after a dot)'` when I do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `this@MainActivity` to reference the outer class instance.

Tip: I couldn't remember the syntax either, so I just wrote a simple example in Java and asked IntelliJ to convert the class to Kotlin to find the answer.

Comment: There is another "trick". Write a variable with the correct type `val a: MainActivity =` and invoke smart completion (Ctrl+Shift+Space). IntelliJ will suggest the expression `this@MainActivity`.

Comment: Followup question in case anybody feels like asking: why is this _not_ done the same as in Java? This is a very strange syntax I've never seen anywhere else.

Comment: Don't forget to use `inner` keyword before the class declaration like `inner class A()`.